# java - curry an existing static function

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, currying

To take full advantage of function composition in Java I'd like to curry some existing static functions that I commonly use.  A perfect candidate for currying is Apache Commons [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

For a concrete example let's say I wanted to curry the [`StringUtils.remove(String str, String remove`)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#remove-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method to provide a function called (say) `removeCommas`.

One possible implementation is:

```
Function<String, String> removeCommas = s -> StringUtils.remove(s, ",");
```

However this isn't currying.  I would expect to be able to use method reference operator (eg `StringUtils::remove`) to achieve this in a more functional way, but I cannot figure out what the syntax would look like.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not clear on the objective. Are you trying to curry `remove()`, or are you trying create a function to remove commas?

Comment: `remove` is just an example.. in theory I should be able to take any java method with an arity >=2 and curry it to make it arity 1, I'm asking how one would do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can curry `remove()` like this:

```
Function<String, Function<String, String>> remove = r -> s -> StringUtils.remove(s, r);
Function<String, String> removeCommas = remove.apply(",");
```

If you prefer the method reference, you can make a generic helper method to curry any fixed-arity method:

```
static <T, U, R> Function<T, Function<U, R>> curry(BiFunction<T, U, R> function) {
    return a -> b -> function.apply(a, b);
}
// ...
Function<String, Function<String, String>> remove = curry(StringUtils::remove);
```

Note that this helper follows the parameter order, so the above function would capture the target string before the removal string. There's no way to reorder parameters in a method reference, so you would have to pick an order and stick with it.

Comment: There is a way apply the parameters in reverse order. The library I wrote does this. I appended it to my answer.

Comment: @mike Do you know what a method reference is?

Comment: Yup. But my remark is not about method references. Basically, I save the parameters in an object array, and apply them all to the Method object, after the last parameter was added.

Comment: @mike Not sure what your point is. Are you disagreeing with something in my answer?

Comment: I was and am referring to `Note that this helper follows the parameter order, so the above function would capture the target string before the removal string`.

Comment: @mike You think my helper does something different than I described?

Comment: Everything as described. You can't call it currying, though, since the order of the parameters is wrong. But this is only a technical detail.

Comment: @mike Right or wrong depends on the the use case. My first solution reverses the parameters for OP's specific example. The second solution is a more generic approach that relies on the parameter order.

Answer (score 3):

Plain Java does not provide syntactic sugar for currying. However, if you are willing to use a third party library, you may use [Javaslang](http://javaslang.io).

Beside functions of arity 0..8, it also contains checked functions (of same arity) which allow to throw exceptions. These provide the following features:

- partial application
- curried functions
- tupled functions
- memoized functions (= caching of results)
- functions with reversed parameters
- function lifting
- ...

In our concrete case here, we need the reversed parameter list before currying (or partially applying) the remove method:

```
// currying
final Function1<String, Function1<String, String>> curried =
        Function2.of(StringUtils::remove).reversed().curried();

// partial application with reversed parameters
final Function1<String, String> removeCommas =
        Function2.of(StringUtils::remove).reversed().apply(",");
```

Function1 extends Java's Function, Function2 extends Java's BiFunction for interoperability reasons.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang

Answer (score 0):

Functional languages have currying, because many functional languages are limited to functions with only one parameter. This is inherited from the lambda calculus, which is a formal language/system in the discipline of mathematical logic.

Currying overcomes this limitation, however plain Java does not support currying.

---

<sub>Years ago I wrote a library called [jcurry](https://github.com/mbe24/jcurry), here is an [example](https://github.com/mbe24/jcurry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/beyene/jcurry/example/Example.java). Maybe you find it useful.</sub>

Comment: "mathematical functions which only have one parameter" whaat?

Comment: In math a function is `f(x)`.

Comment: In a function one element from domain corresponds to exactly one element from codomain. To be honest, I do not understand your answer.

Comment: And domain may be a cross product (e.g. `RxR`)... on which a function `f(x, y)` can be defined.

Comment: But then `x \in RxR`, which would be a single argument again. But anyway, I'll try to rephrase my answer and leave any assumptions on math out.

Comment: Done. I've included a reference to the lambda calculus instead.

Comment: Sorry @mike I don't see how this is an answer to the question